# JSon Parsing not working

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON data from the flixter API to import it to my blog.
In the example below, I tried using JavaScript to output the cast info for the movie expendables.

My full goal would be to get it to output the information
"Sylvester Stallone as Barney Ross, Jason Statham as Lee Christmas" and so on.

Here is my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k3V9p/3/

```
     var jsontext = '{
    "cast": [{
        "id": "162664630",
        "name": "Sylvester Stallone",
        "characters": ["Barney Ross"]
    }, {
        "id": "162653720",
        "name": "Jason Statham",
        "characters": ["Lee Christmas"]
    }, {
        "id": "162652223",
        "name": "Jet Li",
        "characters": ["Yin Yang"]
    }, {
        "id": "162664307",
        "name": "Dolph Lundgren",
        "characters": ["Gunnar Jensen"]
    }, {
        "id": "162670654",
        "name": "Chuck Norris",
        "characters": ["Booker"]
    }, {
        "id": "326392465",
        "name": "Terry Crews",
        "characters": ["Hale Caesar"]
    }, {
        "id": "770731413",
        "name": "Randy Couture",
        "characters": ["Toll Road"]
    }, {
        "id": "770833479",
        "name": "Liam Hemsworth",
        "characters": ["Billy the Kid"]
    }, {
        "id": "770704326",
        "name": "Scott Adkins",
        "characters": ["Hector"]
    }, {
        "id": "770670020",
        "name": "Nan Yu",
        "characters": ["Maggie"]
    }, {
        "id": "162670708",
        "name": "Jean-Claude Van Damme",
        "characters": ["Jean Vilain"]
    }, {
        "id": "162652509",
        "name": "Bruce Willis",
        "characters": ["Mr. Church"]
    }, {
        "id": "162662233",
        "name": "Arnold Schwarzenegger",
        "characters": ["Trench"]
    }, {
        "id": "489251774",
        "name": "Amanda Ooms",
        "characters": ["Pilar"]
    }, {
        "id": "377608335",
        "name": "Charisma Carpenter",
        "characters": ["Lacy"]
    }, {
        "id": "771417014",
        "name": "Nikolette Noel",
        "characters": ["Sophia"]
    }],
    "links": {
        "rel": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771238417.json"
    }
}';
    var titles = JSON.parse(jsontext);
    document.write(titles.cast);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the first problem you have is the JSON.parsing (which dystroy has perfectly answered), after solving that you will have to deal with rendering which you could do like this: ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k3V9p/7/))

```
var titles = {
    "cast": [{
        "id": "162664630", "name": "Sylvester Stallone", "characters": ["Barney Ross"]
    }, {"id": "162653720", "name": "Jason Statham", "characters": ["Lee Christmas"]
    }, {"id": "162652223", "name": "Jet Li", "characters": ["Yin Yang"]
    }, {"id": "162664307", "name": "Dolph Lundgren", "characters": ["Gunnar Jensen"]
    }, {"id": "162670654", "name": "Chuck Norris", "characters": ["Booker"]
    }, {"id": "326392465", "name": "Terry Crews", "characters": ["Hale Caesar"]
    }, {"id": "770731413", "name": "Randy Couture", "characters": ["Toll Road"]
    }, {"id": "770833479", "name": "Liam Hemsworth", "characters": ["Billy the Kid"]
    }, {"id": "770704326", "name": "Scott Adkins", "characters": ["Hector"]
    }, {"id": "770670020", "name": "Nan Yu", "characters": ["Maggie"]
    }, {"id": "162670708", "name": "Jean-Claude Van Damme", "characters": ["Jean Vilain"]
    }, {"id": "162652509", "name": "Bruce Willis", "characters": ["Mr. Church"]
    }, {"id": "162662233", "name": "Arnold Schwarzenegger", "characters": ["Trench"]
    }, {"id": "489251774", "name": "Amanda Ooms", "characters": ["Pilar"]
    }, {"id": "377608335", "name": "Charisma Carpenter", "characters": ["Lacy"]
    }, {"id": "771417014", "name": "Nikolette Noel", "characters": ["Sophia"]
    }],
        "links": {
        "rel": "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/771238417.json"
    }
},
star,
staring = [];

for (star = 0; star < titles.cast.length; star++) {
    staring.push(titles.cast[star].name + ' as ' + titles.cast[star].characters[0]);
}

document.getElementById('Credits').innerHTML = staring.join(', ');
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is with end of lines in your string literal. You can write them like this :

```
var jsontext = '{\
  "cast": [{\
```

But in your case, it's not clear if you really need JSON, as you could directly create your object as

```
var titles = {
   cast": [{
   ...
```

Comment: You would only need to call JSON.parse if you received a string from something like the value of a `textarea` or from an AJAX response.  Otherwise you can take advantage of the fact that JSON is just vanilla JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: @dystroy Thank you for you quick response however if i am understanding correctly, i would have to edit the json data i'm getting from the api service(flixter)? If not, it possible you could edit the jsFiddl so i could see it in action?

Comment: @Craig No, when you receive the JSON from the server, you don't have any problem with the end of lines. You only have this problem because you use a JavaScript string literal in your script.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change what flixster api is returning to you.

The problem is you need to call the API directly... do not copy&paste the result.

See the usage here http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/examples

Just do the Ajax call and onSuccess (searchCallback in the example) you will have the data parsed in json already.

Comment: Thank You, in my rush i did not see this